# How do I get the name of the highest value in a group in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Country       Continent      Population 
--- -------       -------------  ------------
 0  United States North America  329,451,665
 1  Canada        North America   37,602,103
 2  Brazil        South America  210,147,125
 3  Argentina     South America   43,847,430
```

I want to group by the continent, and get the name of the country with the highest population in that continent, so basically I want my result to look as follows:

```
Continent      Country
----------     -------------
North America  United States
South America  Brazil
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why is it `Brazil` for `South America` ?

Comment: `df.sort_values('Population').drop_duplicates(['Continent', 'Country'], keep='last')`

Answer (score 1):

Use `idxmax` to get index of the max row:

```
df['Population'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Population'].str.replace(',', ''))
idx = df.groupby('Continent')['Population'].idxmax()
df.loc[idx]
```

Result:

```
         Country      Continent  Population
0  United States  North America   329451665
2         Brazil  South America   210147125
```